# How to insert / store multiple items in a single cell DataBase using PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a column named - `points` in a table 
I need to insert/store multiple values inside a points column field and display them as list items
EX: points (column):
[100% Wool, Width approx 72cm / 28 inches, Can be used as an area carpet]

output required:

- 100% Wool
- Width approx 72cm / 28 inches
- Can be used as an area carpet

My way was to do it with an array, but how?
May I know any other ways to handle it using php & MySQL.

Comment: Trying to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store an array in a single table column. But first you need to convert the array into a string. For examle:

```
$dataarray = [
    'title' => '100% Wool',
    'properties' => [
        'Width approx 72cm / 28 inches',
        'Can be used as an area carpet'
    ]
]
$datastring = serialize($dataarray); // returns string

// save to to your database, using $datastring as a value for the 'points' column
[...]
```

After you read the data from your database again, simply un-serialize the stored data and you get the array back:

```
// load data from database
[...]

$datastring = $row['points'];
$dataarray = unserialize($datastring);
print_r($dataarray);
```

be aware that there are limits to the amount of data a single mysql-column can store, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

as an alternative to  `serialize()` / `unserialize()`, you may use `json_encode()` / `json_dencode()`, which is a bit safer and uses a more universal storage format, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php